# XML - receiving cvc-complex-type.2.4.a error when validating against schema

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm sure this is very simple, but I'm getting a validation error that I can't sort out. If I have only one `link_text` and `href` element occurrence, it validates fine. If I include more than one `link_text` and `href` elements I get a validation error:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'link_text'. One of '{"http://www.codeshop.ca/ns":href}' is expected.

I set them both to unbounded so I'm having trouble figuring this out. I have included a link to the code:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d04d007056b10a76b251

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does my answer help you with your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `sequence` content model group in your schema. This **requires** you to use the elements in the exact order that you specified.

Your schema says:

```
<!--Menu containing links -->
<element name="menu">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element name="link_text" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="href" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
         </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

This means that within `<menu>` you first need to specified 1 or more `<link_text>` elements and then one or more `<href>` elements. (and you can't have character content, so you need to delete the '+' from your input file)

For reference, since you didn't include it in your question directly, only with a link, the section in your input that causes the error is:

```
<menu>
    <link_text>Vice Fightland Magazine</link_text>
    <href>http://www.vice.com</href>
+
    <link_text>MMAJunkie</link_text>
    <href>http://www.mmajunkie.com</href>
</menu>
```

It looks like you want each link_text and href to belong together. Apart from the '+' that you need to remove, you can model this as a sequence of sequences:

```
<element name="menu">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <element name="link_text" />
                <element name="href" />
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
```

However personally I would change the input to:

```
<menu>
    <link>
        <text>Vice Fightland Magazine</text>
        <href>http://www.vice.com</href>
    </link>
    <link>
        <text>MMAJunkie</text>
        <href>http://www.mmajunkie.com</href>
    </link>
</menu>
```

It makes it clearer that the text and the href belong together and it makes it possible to create a complexType for it that you can reference in multiple locations and in other ways that xml schema supports for complex types (instead of just model groups).